# Problem re-creating a forloop from a Kaggle competition

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

Recently for a course at University, our teacher asked us to re-create one of Kaggle's competitions. I chose to do [this one](https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/overview/description).

I was able to follow the tutorial relatively well, until I reached the for loop they wrote to clean the text in the data frame. Here it is:

```
# Get the number of reviews based on the dataframe column size
num_reviews = train["review"].size

# Initialize an empty list to hold the clean reviews
clean_train_reviews = []

# Loop over each review; create an index i that goes from 0 to the length
# of the movie review list 
for i in xrange( 0, num_reviews ):
    # Call our function for each one, and add the result to the list of
    # clean reviews
    clean_train_reviews.append( review_to_words( train["review"][i] ) )
```

My problem is when they use 'xrange' in the loop, since that was never assigned to anything during the tutorial and is, therefore, returning an error when I try to run the code. I also checked the code provided by the author on [github](https://github.com/wendykan/DeepLearningMovies/blob/master/BagOfWords.py) and they did the exact same thing. So, my question is: Is this simply a mistake on their end or am I missing something? If I am not missing anything, what should be in the place of'xrange'?

I've tried assigning the relevant dataframe column to a variable I can then use here, but I then get a TypeError, stating 'Series' object is not callable.  My knowledge in Python is a bit elementary still, so I apologize if I am simply missing something obvious. Appreciate any help!

Comment: `xrange` has been depreciated in python 3. Just replace `xrange` with `range`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

range and xrange are both python functions, the only thing, xrange is used only in python 2.

Both are implemented in different ways and have different characteristics associated with them. The points of comparison are:

Return Type:
Type 'list',
Type 'xrange'

Memory:
Big size,
Small size

Operation Usage:
As range() returns the list, all the operations that can be applied on the list can be used on it. On the other hand, as xrange() returns the xrange object, operations associated to list cannot be applied on them, hence a disadvantage.

Speed:
Because of the fact that xrange() evaluates only the generator object containing only the values that are required by lazy evaluation, therefore is faster in implementation than range().

More info:
[source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/range-vs-xrange-python/)

You are probably having this issue because you are using python3.
Just use range function instead.